# Wrap widget creates random spacing and alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to convert a text into a list of button widgets, such that business logic can be added to any of the words. So I create the buttons as children of `Wrap`. These should be left aligned (line breaks) with even spaces. Unfortunately, they are not.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (int i = 0; i < widget.words.length; i++)
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              minWidth: 1,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
              child: PlatformText(
                  widget.words[i].word,
                  style: widget.words[i].selected ?
                  TextStyle(color: widget.selectColor)
                      :
                      TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
                  //Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1
              ),
              onPressed: () => widget.bloc.add(CsWordSelected(i)),
            )
        ]);
  }
```

`alignment` and `runAlignment` have `WrapAlignment.start` as default, entering the argument does not change the outcome.

As you can see, they are neither left aligned nor centered, and some buttons have a smaller spacing than others in a row. Any ideas why this is so? Or is this kind of a bug in Flutter?

[image]

=== UPDATE ===

this does not happen with CupertinoButton, I just discovered. With Cupertino, it is rendered as expected

Comment: Can you include `PlatformText`. I'm testing on web and  widget  is working as expected.

Comment: Cheers! PlatformText is an external package to have one code base for iOS and Android. I have just replaced `PlatformText` with `Text` and have also switched back to MaterialButton => issue persists. I am using the iOS simulator